How do I mock Deno built-in methods like Deno.Command()?
I have a method that triggers an external binary. For testing, I would like to mock the specific Deno.Command() call and control the values "returned" from the external command. How can I mock methods on the Deno object?

This solution is based on one of the Deno.Command() examples in the Deno documentation:
This is an example of code I want to test:
export async function testme() {
    const command = new Deno.Command(Deno.execPath(), {
        args: [
          "eval",
          "console.log('Hello'); console.error('world')",
        ],
      });
      const { code, stdout } = await command.output();
      console.assert(code === 0, 'exit code is 0');
      return new TextDecoder().decode(stdout);
}

testme().then(
    (output) => {
        console.log('Done! Got: ' + output);
    }
)

If I save that as script.js I can run it with deno run -A script.js and get the expected output.
This seems to work as a corresponding test for this method:
import { Buffer } from "node:buffer";

// the tested method
import { testme } from "./script.js";

import { stub } from "https://deno.land/std@0.211.0/testing/mock.ts";
import { assertEquals } from "jsr:@std/assert@1";

Deno.test("fake command", async function () {
  const stubbedCommand = stub(Deno, "Command", function (path, args) {
    console.log({path, args});
    return {
      output: () => {
        return Promise.resolve({
          code: 0,
          stdout: Buffer.from("Foo"),
          stderr: Buffer.from("world"),
        });
      },
    };
  });
  assertEquals(await testme(), "Foo");
  stubbedCommand.restore();
});

and I can run the test using deno test -A script.test.js.
